# Why is selenium not working properly on my mac?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using python 3 and selenium 2.53.6 on mac and it does open firefox but not to the page I specified. I try to open "inventwithpython.com" but all my program does is launch firefox and return this error.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
```

I also getting below error:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py",
>   line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
>       % (self.profile.path)) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the
>   profile. Profile Dir:
>   /var/folders/4c/gsw7v5b118j406zxj3lxctt40000gn/T/tmpv963_mt0 If you
>   specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for
>   details.

Comment: you are not using the latest versions of: firefox, selenium, geckodriver.  upgrade these and your code will work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this? and let me know what happenes?

```
#!/your/shebang/line/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/your/path/to/actual/firefox/binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
```

make sure the path to binary is the actual one you launch when you touch Firefox normally.

EDIT:

oh and before i forget, make sure you do this as well. just to be sure.

```
pip install -U selenium
```

because there was a fix for profiles a bit ago if i remember right. so lets make sure that's not a thing.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question at all.  the OP states that it is launching Firefox... so it obviously is finding the binary location just fine.

Comment: while you might be right, the idea here is to test if his environment is the same as what im thinking. because he could launch firefox, but if the profile cant be loaded, it could be the wrong one. selenium tries to get the right binary from the system. but its not always right. to specify the binary used in his daily life might just help things go smoothly. and if it doesnt, then it eliminates a whole host of other problems and narrows the possibilities.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an interactive debugger.  Clarifying questions and advice are acceptable in comments... but answers are supposed to actually be answers, not vague debugging tips.

Comment: alright, ill try to segregate these more in the future